# OAuth 2.0 Playground "Something bad happened: 500 HTTP error"

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, oauth2-playground

When I following the procedure of the following article: https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1.

When clicking on the button `Exchange authorization code for tokens` the Google's server returns me:

> Something bad happened: 500 HTTP error. Message:   
>         
>            500 Internal Server Error
>
> ## 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

here an image illustrating the situation: 
[image: when trying to exchange the authorization code for token, the Google's server returns me a 500 error]

How can I get my OAuth's token? 
Maybe someone know another place to get one?

Answer (score 0):

First verify what the "OAuth flow" is set to.

If *Server-side*, and when using your own OAuth credentials be sure to add your Project's own **OAuth Client ID** *and* **OAuth Client secret**.

Missing one can throw this particular 500 HTTP error.